# Телеграмм бот. Пересылка сообщений оператору

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Язык python
библиотека telegram bot API

У меня есть меню при переходе в определённый раздел пользователю вылазит сообщение о том, как правильно заполнить форму после чего пользователь заполняет форму по примеру, ну примерно он пишет email, имя , фамилию и т.д. и вот как это, его сообщение, после отправки переслать оператору ?
Заранее спасибо

```
elif message.text == 'Как Оформить':
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Оформленине ')
       
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Заявка на оформление ')
        
        back = types.KeyboardButton('Назад')

        markup.add(item1, item2, back)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Как Оформить', reply_markup = markup)
```

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй метод bot.foward_message он пересылает любое сообщение в том числе и медиа файлы, туда куда укажешь)

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('***') #Укажи здесь ключ бота
TO_CHAT_ID = *** #укажи здесь айди группы в тг




@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def all_messages(message):
    bot.forward_message(TO_CHAT_ID, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]